# Primitive for $f(x)=\frac{2+3x+x^2}{x(x^2+1)}.$

Tags: calculus, integration

I have to find a primitive of $$f(x)=\frac{2+3x+x^2}{x(x^2+1)}.$$

I tried to use partial decomposition but I am having trouble to evaluate this fraction at $0$.

Using this method we have $f(x)=\frac{a}{x}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2+1}$.

How can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $a(x^2+1)+(bx+c)x=x^2+3x+2$, so

$x=0$ gives $a=2$,

the coefficient of $x$ gives $c=3$, and

the coefficient of $x^2$ gives $a+b=1$, so $b=-1$.

This leaves you with $\displaystyle\int\left(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{-x+3}{x^2+1}\right)dx=2\int\frac{1}{x}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2x}{x^2+1}dx+3\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Comment: Right, I forgot to multiply by $x$. Silly me. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
1.$\displaystyle \int \frac{2x}{x^2+1} dx=\int \frac{1}{x} dx=\log|x|+C$

2.$\displaystyle \int \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx=\arctan x+C $